# How to install chromedriver in jenkins for automatic update?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

In the Jenkins server, we have a jenkins job to run the selenium tests with python (3) and pytest is the runner for the these tests. I am having trouble with the version of the chromedriver and need to find a way to update chromedriver automatically as the DevOPs team doesn't want to spend time maintaining it.

I have got a requirements.txt file with the dependencies which now include a chromedriver-binary pkg.

I need to know how I can update the chromedriver or anything else I need to avoid this issue. Also, how can I avoid an encounter this issue in the future.

Any helpful links/direction would be highly appreciated.

I have tried to use a different python package called 
chromedriver-binary
pip install chromedriver-binary 78.0.3904.11.0 
https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/#description

Tried changing the configuration on the test runner few times. but all unsuccessful, obviously

```
if jenkins:
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
# options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-beta'. # old code
options.add_argument('headless')
print("\ninitiating headless chrome browser...\n")
```

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f982183c978>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76","stacktrace":"#0 0x5575afc695e9 \\u003Cunknown>\\n"}}'}
```

Comment: The error tell you the webdriver you installed not support the chrome browser on Jenkins slave.  It only make sense when you can know which chromedriver version to install in advance.  Did the `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` is controlled by you? If it's installed by DevOPs  team and its automatic update turn on, how you can get the browser version, then find out the corresponding chromedriver.

Comment: The better way it's you install a fixed version browser into a customize folder (not to overwrite the default one ) in each time testing, then install corresponding chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic update means: Silent download, unzip, task1, task2,etc  at scheduled intervals: daily, weekly, monthly, etc

## Proposed steps

- Create a free style job, with this shell tasks:

  - backup driver: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
  - download latest drive
  - override the old driver
- Schedule this job in **build trigger section**.  Read this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-job-schedule)

Comment: Thanks mate. I found a good post few days ago about running some bash scripts. Should have saved it! But thanks for the suggestion.